# How to show 10 elements at a time using angular2-infinite-scroll module?

Tags: angular, typescript, infinite-scroll

I am using angular 2 infinite scroll module,and I want to show 10 elements at a time , when the user hits the scrollDown()  ,the next 10 elements have to be shown and the scroll bar should be updated  accordingly ,trying various methods but nothing has worked so far,any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

This is my code.

```
`infinite-scroll
            [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"

            [infiniteScrollThrottle]="500"

            [scrollWindow]="false"
            (scrolled)="onScrollDown()"
            (scrolledUp)="onScrollUp()"

  style="overflow: auto;height:250px;width:350px" >
            <div class="scrollBar">
            <ul *ngFor="let item of list" >
             <li>{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
            </div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **slice** pipe in order to limit the items you see on screen.

You'll need a variable to keep the total number of items shown on screen in.

A simple example would look like this:

```html
<div>
  <h2 (click)="limit=limit+2">more</h2>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list | slice:0:limit">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
  {{limit}}
</div>
```

You can see it working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qvZORpSukcysH9C4Qnil?p=preview).

In your case I guess you could use **(scrolled)** to increase the limit.

```html
<div infinite-scroll
            [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"

            [infiniteScrollThrottle]="500"

            [scrollWindow]="false"
            (scrolled)="limit=limit+10"
            (scrolledUp)="onScrollUp()"

  style="overflow: auto;height:250px;width:350px" >
            <div class="scrollBar">
            <ul *ngFor="let item of list | slice:0:limit" >
             <li>{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```